Hello World! using WinAPI does not do anything
I use the Netwide Assembler as my assembler.
I am attempting to create a program printing the string Hello World but I don’t succeed.
I put all arguments on the stack as the calling convention dictates.
The CC says the first argument needs to be placed in RCX, the second one in RDX, the third one in R8, fourth in R9 and the fifth at [RSP + 32].
So I wrote this program:
section .data
    phrase db 'Hello World'     ; create new var with size of db(Double World)
    charsWritten dd 0           ; set the var up is as things which will be printed out
section .text
    global _start
    extern ExitProcess          ; import the function ExitProcess to return 0
    extern WriteConsoleA        ; import the command of printing out
    extern GetStdHandle         ; descriptor
    _start:
        mov  rcx, -10           ; set 1st argument
        call GetStdHandle       ; call the result was saved in rax
        mov r8, rax             ; save result

        mov rcx, r8             ; set the saved result up as 1st argument
        mov rdx, phrase         ; set the pointer as 2nd argument
        mov r8, 11              ; set r8 as 3rd argument with data 11 (length)
        mov r9, charsWritten    ; set the pointer of printed words out as 4th arg.
        mov qword [rsp + 32], 0 ; set zero into stack as 5th argument
        call WriteConsoleA      ; call printing out

        mov rcx, 0              ; its first argument of returning 0
        call ExitProcess        ; call return with 0 as first argument of it

Yet this program seemingly doesn’t do anything. No mistakes. I tried to set up this .exe file. The exit status is 0 (success).
C:\Users\Мила ПК\Desktop>nasm -f win64 test.asm -o test.o

C:\Users\Мила ПК\Desktop>ld -o test.exe test.o -lkernel32
C:\Users\Мила ПК\Desktop>test.exe
C:\Users\Мила ПК\Desktop>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

Other details I deem relevant to the question:



datum
value




operating system
Windows 11 Pro


system
64‑bit system


processor
Intel i7




What does it do?  You can't just say "it doesn't do anything", describe the steps you do and what the behavior is.

You need to allocate 48  bytes on the stack before calling any functions. 32 bytes because that is required by the Windows API, an additional 8 bytes to hold the fifth parameter to the function, and an additional 8 bytes to make sure the stack remains 16-byte aligned.

okay, i'll show

Kai Burghardt does not recommend using Microsoft Windows. This answer may contain errors.
Nop
You may be tempted starting with a Hello, World program, but actually your very first W64 program written in assembly should be this:
global _start
section .text
_start:
    ret

In UNIX‑like environments, the loader usually jmps to the entry point.
However, in Winblows the entry point is essentially called† placing a return address on top of the stack you can return to.

As a sidebar, an infinite loop program can be written like this:
global _start
section .text
_start:
    jmp rax   ; rax containing the address of the entry point

Exit
Now returning from _start is not guaranteed to work properly because it is apparently not officially documented.
The official way uses ExitProcess.
Let’s rewrite the first program using ExitProcess instead.
Stack alignment
First of all, before making any call the ABI expects you to align the stack on 16­‑byte boundaries.
That means the stack pointer written as a hexadecimal number should end in 0.
Since the stack grows downward (toward numerically smaller addresses) a straightforward way of achieving 16‑byte alignment is:
    and RSP, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0

It is fair to assume that an “operating system” adheres to its own calling conventions.
When our program is called† the stack has been aligned, too.
However, the call† puts a return address on top of the stack destroying the alignment (implicit push(RIP) by call).
Therefore when our program commences with the first instruction following _start, the stack pointer (written as a hexadecimal number) ends in 8 (or expressed arithmetically RSP mod 16 = 8 is true).
Thus the above and effectively does the same as a sub RSP, 8.
As we do not intend to use the return address, we can simply discard the return address by popping the stack:
    pop RAX                     ; discard return address, re‑align stack to 16 B

Dark space
The Wix64 ABI asks you to (always) allocate 4 × 8 bytes of shadow space on the stack.
This space may be used by the callee (the function you call) to spill the first four arguments RCX, RDX, R8 and R9.
Spilling means storing the datum somewhere else so the register is freed up for a different use; the original argument value can be retrieved later from said shadow space.
global _start                   ; export _start
extern ExitProcess              ; tell NASM the reference is resolved later

section .text
_start:
    pop RAX                     ; discard return address, re‑align stack to 16 B
    
exit:
    xor ECX, ECX                ; ECX ≔ EXIT_SUCCESS
    sub RSP, 4 * 8              ; reserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    call ExitProcess            ; 32 mod 16 = 0, so stack pointer still aligned

Get output
It is your duty to clean up the stack after a call has finished.
While ExitProcess is (ideally) non‑returning, GetStdHandle does return, so we reverse the effects of sub RSP, 32:
global _start
extern GetStdHandle, ExitProcess

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ  -11    ; a more meaningful constant instead of −11

section .text
_start:
    pop RAX                     ; discard return address, re‑align stack to 16 B

get_output: 
    mov ECX, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE  ; retrieve HANDLE for standard output
    sub RSP, 4 * 8              ; reserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    call GetStdHandle           ; RAX ≔ GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    add RSP, 4 * 8              ; unreserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    
exit:
    xor ECX, ECX                ; ECX ≔ EXIT_SUCCESS
    sub RSP, 4 * 8              ; reserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    call ExitProcess

You may notice half the instructions are just moving the stack pointer back and forth.
You can cut down the juggling, but I recommend postponing that step until your algorithm works as expected, until you do not want to insert or remove anything anymore.
Write output
As you already know the first four parameters are passed in registers.
Any additional parameters are pushed on the stack from right to left.
While doing so you must take account of the shadow space and alignment.
Also, it is preferred to let the assembler calculate the string length instead of doing it by yourself (→ hello_world_length).
global _start
extern GetStdHandle, WriteConsoleA, ExitProcess
default rel                     ; if not specified use RIP‑relative addressing

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE   equ  -11    ; a more meaningful constant instead of −11

; --- initialized data ---------------------------------------------------------
section .data
hello_world:
    db 'Hello, world!', `\r\n`
hello_world_length  equ  $ - hello_world

; --- uninitialized data -------------------------------------------------------
section .bss
result:
    resd 1

; --- executable text ----------------------------------------------------------
section .text
_start:
    pop RAX                     ; discard return address, re‑align stack to 16 B
    
get_output:
    mov ECX, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE  ; retrieve HANDLE for standard output
    sub RSP, 4 * 8              ; reserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    call GetStdHandle           ; RAX ≔ GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    add RSP, 4 * 8              ; unreserve 32 bytes of shadow space

write_hello_world:
    add RSP, 1 * 8              ; keep alignment after push
    
    mov ECX, EAX                ; write destination
    LEA RDX, [hello_world]      ; source string start address
    mov R8, hello_world_length  ; length of source string
    LEA R9, [result]            ; destination for number of bytes written
    push 0                      ; reserved, must be zero
    
    add RSP, 4 * 8              ; reserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    call WriteConsoleA
    sub RSP, 6 * 8              ; reclaim 48 bytes of stack space
    
exit:
    xor ECX, ECX                ; ECX ≔ EXIT_SUCCESS
    sub RSP, 4 * 8              ; reserve 32 bytes of shadow space
    call ExitProcess

; vim: set filetype=nasm:

Apparently, even on Win64 the size of a HANDLE is 32 bits so using 32‑bit registers is sufficient.
Errors
The used I/O functions may fail so you should check the return values.
GetStdHandle may return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE which you should not pass on to WriteConsoleA.
†: For explanation purposes we presume it was called. An intervening stub jmping to _start can be ignored.

"Kai Burghardt does not recommend using Microsoft Windows." - Kinda hard to follow this advice without rationale. "However, in Winblows [...]" - Oh, I see. A Linux fanboi it is. Can we remove the useless banter?

@I Maybe does not endorse is more appropriate? I mean, I did make this a Community Wiki post because I do not have any experience in Windoofus programming, so it probably contains if not errors, then poor style. Oh, and I do not love Linux (anymore).

That doesn't change things; a rationale is still missing. Besides, the size of a HANDLE is 64 bits on 64-bit Windows. Passing a handle in a 32-bit subregister is thus a bug even when inconsequential.
